# CSS :hover text-decoration: underline not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I have a problem where on :hover my  tag should be underline with a red color but this doesn't seem to happen on Safari browsers.

This is how it appears on Chrome browser, but on Safari it does not render the red underline.

[image: How it displays in]

Html code

```
<div class="container bot-category">
<div class="row text-center my-5">
   
    <div class="col">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-floating m-1" href="{% url 'bots' %}" role="button" >View all</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1" href="{% url 'support' %}" role="button">Read FAQs</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1" href="" role="button">Botbrary</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
         <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-floating m-1" href="{% url 'bots' %}" role="button">Scripts</a>
    </div>  
    </div>     
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.bot-category a:hover{
background-color: black !important; 
text-decoration: underline 2px solid #f4364c !important; 
color: white !important;
-webkit-decoration:  underline 2px solid #f4364c !important;
```

}

Comment: Could you add some code, please? `text-decoration` property is supported by all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

Comment: You can try with `-webkit-text-decoration-line: underline;` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-decoration-line

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work either on Safari nor Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below piece of code.

```
.bot-category a:hover{
   background-color: black !important; 
   text-decoration: underline 2px solid #f4364c !important; 
   color: white !important;
   -webkit-text-decoration-line:  underline !important;
   -webkit-text-decoration-color: #f4364c !important;
   -webkit-text-decoration-style: solid !important;
   -webkit-text-decoration-thickness: 2px !important;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. However, in my case -webkit-text-decoration-thickness was ignored by Safari.